# Gksu Naulitus is not working

Tags: 12.04, lts, gksu

I am using ubuntu 12.04. I wanted to change permissions of a file so i typed gksu naulitus. it asked my password andstl i entered it and nothing happened. What should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your post title and text you write "naulitus", which is a typo, it should be "nautilus" (replace the "l" and "t").

When you run `gksu nonexistentcommand` or `sudo nonexistentcommand`, the system still asks your password and print an error message after. If you launched `gksu nonexistent` from a terminal you would see this error message, if you launch by other means then you might not see an error message, just nothing would happen, like you described.

It might be easier and safer to do change the permissions of a file using the `sudo chmod` and `sudo chown` commands in a terminal, for example:

```
# make a file readable
sudo chmod +r /path/to/file
# make a file executable
sudo chmod +x /path/to/file
```

If you use `gksu nautilus`, then after you changed the permission, you might forget to close the nautilus window with superuser permissions open, and you might accidentally do something dangerous in it.

Comment: it was a typing mistake.I typed it wrong tn the GNOME terminal. you should down vote for my mistake. sorry

Comment: @user222588 others might make the same mistake, search for "naulitus" and find your post, so it's not all that bad ;-)

Answer (score 0):

To change permission of a file, try it on command line.`gksu nautilus` allows you to open nautilus using superuser permissions.

Changing permission of a file via terminal,

```
sudo chmod +x /path/filename
```

Above command will give execute permission to that file.See [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions) about file permissions.